# Angular 4 [routerLink] unrecognized expression:

Tags: angular

Why browser will console error when I use `<a [routerLink]="['/contacts', contact.id]">{{contact.name}}</a>`.

It navigated to correct component, just only has console error.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/contacts', contact.id]" data-toggle="tab" title="Click to view details">
    {{contact.name}}
</a>
```

Error image:
[image: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /contacts/d022ed37-c7f1-4883-9cd5-62c59f18d3a1]

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /contacts/d022ed37-c7f1-4883-9cd5-62c59f18d3a1

But if I use js to navigate, it works well with no error.

HTML:

```
<a (click)="viewDetail(contact.id)" data-toggle="tab" title="Click to view details">
   {{contact.name}}
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
viewDetail(id: number) {
     this.router.navigate(['/contacts/', id]);
}
```

Comment: This is strange. Your code looks absolutely okay. Have you tried another browser or updating yours?

Comment: @DiabolicWords suggest your code is okay.he is right. just try to rebuild your project and then run again.

Comment: I had a similar issue. For me the issue was with bootstrap/jquery and the use of data-toggle="tab". I removed this from the anchor tag and there was no issue after that.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try it like this.

```
<a [routerLink]="['contacts', contact.id]">{{contact.name}}</a>.
```

Comment: This is correct. You need a slash when you need to separate multiple components, like 'contacts/individual' or 'contacts/organizational'

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<a [routerLink]="['/contacts/', contact.id]">{{contact.name}}</a>.
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed it. I remove the `data-toggle`, and it works without error. But I dont know why it work.