# Checking changes correct but error when cancel

Tags: angular, angular7

I created a canDeactivate guard to check if form data was changed before route changed. It's ok and the message is shown but when I click cancel button I get this error.

[image]

[image]

where **"/admin/evento/fotos/amigos"** is the route that the user will go if will click on Ok button.

**Form changed guard**

```
export interface FormChangedCanDeactivate {
    canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class FormChangedGuard implements CanDeactivate<FormChangedCanDeactivate>{

    canDeactivate(component: FormChangedCanDeactivate) {
        return component.canDeactivate();
    }

}
```

**Component method**

```
...
canDeactivate(): Promise<boolean> | boolean { 
   return this.form.dirty ? confirm(this.mensagemSairSemSalvar) : true;
}
...
```

**Router configuration**

```
... 
{path: 'fotos', component: EventoFotosComponent, canActivate: [UsuarioGuard], canDeactivate: [FormChangedGuard]}, 
...
```

Comment: can you try creating a demo in stackblitz ?

Comment: can you please provide your routerLinks code? Did you search online? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849647/angular-4-routerlink-unrecognized-expression

Comment: @PALLAMOLLASAI yes i did search... route is ok! This error happened when canDeactivate guard return false ..... when return true it's works fine!

Comment: @Allabakash I created a demo ==> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2pfcj8 . In demo works fine! Then I investigated the problem and found! My link is a bootstrap tab and 'data-toggle' attribute causes the problem... I removed it and worked! Any idea?

Comment: yeah, data-toggle expects tab id, since it is reading /admin/evento/fotos/amigos , So it is throwing an error.